# Assign Azure RBAC to Azure AD security group on resource group level

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, rbac, azure-rm

I am trying to figure out how to assign a built-in role from azure to an azure ad group I am creating.
However I don't not understand the logic while reading the documentation.

Here's my terraform code:

az-rbac.tf

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {
}

output "current_subscription_display_name" {
  value = data.azurerm_subscription.current.display_name
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "azuread_sg_cns" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "reader-rbac" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_group.azuread_sg_cns.object_id
}
```

main.tf

```
terraform {

  required_version = ">=0.12"
  
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.15.0"
    }
  }
}
#Configure the Azure Resource Management Provider
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = var.azure_subscription_id
    tenant_id = var.azure_tenant_id
  features {}
}

# Configure the Azure Active Directory Provider
provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id = var.azure_tenant_id
}

#create azure active directory group
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_group" "azuread_sg" {
  display_name     = var.azure_sg_name
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}

#create azure active directory group cns

resource "azuread_group" "azuread_sg_cns" {
  display_name     = var.azuread_sg_cns
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}

#create cost reader group
resource "azuread_group" "azuread_sg_cost-mgmt" {
  display_name     = var.azuread_sg_cost-mgmt
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}

#create azure resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.azure_rg_name
  location = var.azure_resource_group_location
}

#create azure key vault
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "akv" {
  name                        = lower("${var.azure_project_code}-${var.azure_env_code}-akv-01")
  location                    = var.azure_resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = var.azure_tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name = "standard"

}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = lower("${var.azure_project_code}${var.azure_env_code}sa01")
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = var.azure_resource_group_location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "ctnr" {
  name                  = lower("${var.azure_project_code}${var.azure_env_code}ctnr01")
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

variable.tf

```
variable "azure_resource_group_location" {
  default = "west europe"
  description   = "Location of the resource group."
}

variable "azure_subscription_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure Subscription Id"
}

variable "azure_tenant_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure Tenant Id"
}

variable "azure_sg_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure AD Security Group Name"
}

variable "azuread_sg_cns" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure AD Security Group Name CNS"
}

variable "azuread_sg_cost-mgmt" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure AD Security Group Name Cost Mgmt"
}

variable "azure_rg_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure Resource Group Name"
}

variable "azure_client_code" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure Client code"
}

variable "azure_project_code" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure Project Code"
}

variable "azure_env_code" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure Environment Code"
}
```

env.tfvars

```
#Azure tenant id
azure_tenant_id ="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
#Azure subscription
azure_subscription_id = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
#Azure resource group location
azure_resource_group_location = "west europe"
# #Azure ad Sg
azure_sg_name = "sg - eu-dev-test-testproject"
# #Azure ad Sg CNS
azuread_sg_cns = "sg -cns - eu-dev-test-testproject"
#Azure Cost Reader
azuread_sg_cost-mgmt = "sg - Cost Reader - eu-dev-test-testproject"
#Azure RG name
azure_rg_name = "eu-dev-test-testproject"
#Azure project code
azure_project_code = "testproject"
#Azure client code
azure_client_code = "test"
#Environement code : sbx, dev, ppd, prd
azure_env_code="dev"
```

So I tried to create multiples resources such as:

- azure resource group
- azure key vault
- azure storage account with 1 container
- azure security group x3

My expectation is to have the cns sg group to get reader role on the created resource group.
But I keep failing as I don't understand how to make my code understand it has to assign the role to the resource group level to the security group cns I am creating while running the code.

Here's the error message with the current code:

[image]

Comment: `azuread_group.azuread_sg_cns` is a resource in your script, not a data source, therefore drop `data.` prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My expectation is to have the cns sg group to get reader role on the created resource group.

Thanks to **Kombajn zbożowy** for suggesting same.

> If you are using resource block for creation of azure ad group but calling it as **data.azuread_group**, which is not declared.

You can use the following **Terraform** code to assign the **Reader** role to a group at the resource group level.

```
provider  "azurerm" {
subscription_id =  "a34e2b59-xxxxxxxxx-b4a8-ebdc1f96c865"
tenant_id =  "89xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-55277a8d958a"
features {}
}
provider  "azuread" {
tenant_id =  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-55277a8d958a"
}
data  "azurerm_client_config"  "azuread_sg_cns" {
}
resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "venkat-rg"{
name =  "venkat-RG"
location =  "eastus"
}
resource  "azuread_group"  "azuread_sg_cns" {
display_name =  "azuread_sg_cns"
security_enabled =  true
}
resource  "azurerm_role_assignment"  "reader-rbac" {
scope =  azurerm_resource_group.venkat-rg.id
role_definition_name =  "Reader"
principal_id =  azuread_group.azuread_sg_cns.object_id
}
```

**Terraform plan:**

[image]

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

Once ran the above code resources are created and **Reader** role are also applied to the group.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I understood my error with the usage of data instead of resource. Take care!